# Highcharts cannot read property 'series' of undefined

Tags: highcharts

I'm seeing this error when I create a line chart with a single y-axis.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined highcharts.3.0.1.js:147

It seems that the series is a bit displaced to the left. The leftmost tool tip is hanging off the chart where the y-axis names are showing. All the tooltips are off a bit and if I mouse all the way to the right of the chart I see this error over and over in the console.

Interestingly, if I zoom in and then hit the 'reset-zoom' the chart renders properly and the problem goes away.

unfortunately, creating a fiddle will be hard as I build my config options on the fly. I am using addSeries to add my series to an empty chart once it has been displayed.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips.

-Dale

Comment: Here is line number in the uncompressed file Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined highcharts.3.0.1.src.js:8982

Comment: Could you recreate your example in the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: As I said in my original posting that would be very difficult as I build the config on the fly using addseries and addaxis api calls. I'm hoping that by giving the exact line number and a thorough description someone at HighCharts will point me in the right direction. I can also add that if I add a 2nd y-axis (opposite) the problem does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

In general, without code it is really hard to find issue, just copy your 'options on the fly' which reproduce issue, please.

However, most probably you are trying to add series for axis, which doesn't exists. For example:

```
yAxis: { },
series: [{ yAxis: 1 }] <-- obviously there is only one yAxis
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Pawel! I'm writing my code in GWT and using a few native methods to access the chart. In my code I load a config file using jQuery & call a native method to add series to the chart. My config  defines a single yAxis and no series. Then I add a series by doing the following: $wnd.chart.addSeries({          
          yAxis: 0,          
          name: "cost",
                        data: series,                
                        color: someColor        
                 }, false);

Comment: I also add the category (dates) on the fly by doing $wnd.chart.xAxis[0].categories = dates; I have double checked that the number of series entries and the number of dates are the same size.

Comment: And you never-ever add `$wnd.chart.addSeries({ yAxis: 1, name: "xyz", data: series, color: someColor }, false);`? To set categories in the fly use `$wnd.chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(dates);`. Also, if you are using GWT Highcharts, there may be an error in that adapter.

Comment: The strange thing is that when I zoom in and then "reset zoom" the issue goes away and the chart renders correctly.

Comment: Could you post link to that site? Or create simple demo on your server with that issue and fake data? I don't have any better ideas why this is not working.

Comment: no I am not using GWT adapter. Yes, users can add a 2nd series like you've shown and when they do the problem goes away and the chart renders fine. It only appears to happen when I add a single series. Before adding the 2nd series I do the following $wnd.chart.addAxis({
    opposite: true,
    showEmpty: false,
    id: 'right_axis',
             title: {
                 text: '',
                 style: {
                     color: someColor,
                     fontSize: '15px'
                 }
             },

Comment: Hi Pawel,I think I may know what's triggering the error? In my code I was adding each series with an extra parameter of false (do not render) and then calling $wnd.chart.redraw(); When I removed the extra parameter from addSeries and commented out the redraw the error not longer appears in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class xyzComponent implements OnInit {
  highcharts = Highcharts;
  chart;
  chartCallback;
  title = 'myHighchart';
  chartConstructor = "chart";
  chartOptions: {};

ngOnInit() {
    this.chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            type: "spline"
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Vegetation and Soil Moisture Index'
        },
    }
}
```

}

```
it's for Angualar
```